Cover old exhaust fan vent from outside home
I recently moved into a house built in 70s. I discovered an uncovered vent outside my kitchen that I want to cover up from outside to prevent any pests. Was wondering if someone has any suggestions. I have added a picture for reference.


Do you want to keep it potentially operational for the future, or just get rid of it entirely?

There are a few things that can be done.
1- You can remove the termination plate. Fill the resulting void with wood or metal and stucco over. Paint to match and it is practically unnoticeable.
2- You can leave the termination plate. Fill the round hole with expandable foam. Cut it flush when dry and paint. (this is not especially aesthetically pleasing.)
3-You can do step 2 and add a metal cover over the round hole. Caulk and then paint.
4- You can just cover the square plate with a blank square plate. Caulk the edges and paint.
